# How to using open and .write to write string + variables value into a file on the same line?

Tags: python

I want to take input from the user containing a string, store that string into a variable and write it inside another strings line into a file.

I've tried using open and .write and using (%s) to add the input to the wrote line.

```
outF = open("file.txt", "w")
string = raw_input("enter string to add!")
outF.write('string data to write (%s)', % string)
outF.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to accomplish this without overwriting the file? In that case, `open("file.txt", "a")` should work (this appends to `file.txt`, rather than overwriting it)

Comment: Do you want to append new line into your existing file?

Comment: Get rid of that comma in the `write()` call - that makes it parse as two parameters, one being a literal string and one being gibberish.

Comment: Afterwards I get this error @jasonharper: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```py
outF = open("file.txt", "a") #append mode if u wish to add more data to the file later
string = raw_input("enter string to add!")
string_new="string u want to add before"+string #add strings wherever u need
outF.write(string_new)
outF.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this suits you

```
with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    x = file.read()
with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    print(x)
    sentence = f"{x} {input('Add something: ')}. End." 
    file.write(sentence)
```

Comment: The string needs to be in the middle of the text for example "I saw ____ at starbucks" where ____ is where the input needs to be added.

Comment: don't use bare excepts